# If a former employer did not pursue a creative idea, am I free to pursue it?

Tags: legal, employer, intellectual-property, entrepreneurship

Background: I used to work as design director for an experiential company and, while employed there, I pitched an idea for a new experience that would fit really well within their brand. They thought it sounded cool but never pursued it (for a number of reasons, but probably mostly because of cost and other expansion plans).

I haven't been with the company for 2 years now. Am I safe to pursue my idea, or does that company own the idea forever even though they didn't act on it?

UPDATE: I'm in New York City. I've reviewed the contract and it has lots of stipulations for non-compete (12 months), non-solicitation (12 months), and that kind of stuff. There's also some language of "you agree to devote all of your professional time, energy, skill and efforts exclusively to the performance of your duties for COMPANY."

Comment: VTC - This depends on both your contract and IP Law in your country. IP Law is *highly* specialized and we couldn't even come close to advising.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it safe to use an idea that was conceived by a previous employer?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/8869/is-it-safe-to-use-an-idea-that-was-conceived-by-a-previous-employer)

Comment: @Steve very related and useful, although not a dupe (the one you linked OP didn't come up with the idea, in this post OP was the one who came up with the idea)

Comment: @DarkCygnus agreed that they are not exact duplicates, but the OP clearly states 'while employed', which a) typically means the employer owns the concept and b) the same answer would apply.

Comment: @Steve yes, typically. That's why OP should check contract and NDAs etc. to know for sure

Answer (score 3):

Did you sign a NDA or non-compete agreement?

I suggest you **check your contract and any NDA/non-compete you may have signed**.

(I am not a lawyer) If you didn't chances are you *may* be free to do so... if you did sign something, then chances are you can't, or at least can't for a period of time.

Usually, NDAs and non-compete's state that you agree to not disclose X,Y and Z, and that you can't work for the competitors or other "related" companies for a certain amount of years... the answer to your query is most likely on such documents. Perhaps you may want to consult a lawyer an read your contract

Answer (score 3):

> Am I safe to pursue my idea,

Depends on what exactly your contract says, what agreements you signed what's in your employee handbook and corporate policies, and/or on local labor laws. Specially you want to check out any type of NDA, "confidentiality" and/or "intellectual property assignment" agreements you have signed.

> or does that company own the idea forever

Depends on what exactly your contract says, what agreements you signed what's in your employee handbook and corporate policies, and/or on local labor laws.

"Forever" would be unlikely. Typically this has a clock on it, which starts AFTER you leave the company. If it doesn't have an expiration date, it's probably determined by local labor laws. "Infinite" agreements tend to be considered unreasonable and unenforceable.

> even though they didn't act on it?

That's typically immaterial. If they own it, they own it unless you have specific local labor laws that ownership is contingent on actual use (unlikely)

**Or you can just ask**

Instead of worrying about the legal details, you can just ask. They may allow it freely, grant you a license (with a wide range of possible terms) or may disallowed. Take your hint from there.

Before doing so, you should also scour your paperwork for any agreements and policies about moonlighting. If you want to do work on the side, it may have to be declared and/or approved first.

Comment: +1 for ask. So e companies are glad to release ideas they aren't pursuing as open source thought they might be pickier about commercial use; they may want to be credited for donating that IP to the open source community.. Some may be willing to license the idea to you, for a reasonable or unreasonable peice/percentage/whatever. But if you signed a contract saying it would be theirs, the fact that they haven't used it does _not_ mean they lose the rights to control it... not unless you are willing to wait for any possible parent or copyright period to expire.